# Import image in Java

Tags: java

Im making a simple pong game and want to put a texture over my paddle but I don't know how to import image into my game. I tried doing in like [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Graphics-in-a-Java-Applet) in 3rd example but it doesn't work:

```
Image myImage = getImage(getCodeBase(), "texture.png");
g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0 , 10, 120, this);
```

`g cannot be resolved`

Here's some code:

```
public void run(){
Image myImage = getImage(getCodeBase(), "texture.png");
g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0 , 10, 120, this);
GOval ball = makeBall();
add(ball);
GRect paddleLeft = makePaddle();
GRect paddleRight = makePaddle();
add(paddleLeft);
add(paddleRight);
bounce(ball, paddleLeft, paddleRight);

}

public static GRect makePaddle(){
    GRect result = new GRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    result.setFilled(true);
    result.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    return result;
}
```

the texture.png is for the paddles

EDIT:

I got the texture to load, but I can't make it move with the paddles, I don't know why
WIDTH is width of the paddle, getWidth() - window. I guess the code I use to move the paddle should work for the texture but it doesnt

with the `image.sendToFront()` player's paddle's texture works, but the AI's doesn't

```
if(mouseY<getHeight()-HEIGHT){                                // Player
            paddleLeft.setLocation(WIDTH,mouseY);
            image.setLocation(WIDTH,mouseY);
            image.sendToFront();
        }
        else{
            paddleLeft.setLocation(WIDTH,getHeight()-HEIGHT);
            image.setLocation(WIDTH,getHeight()-HEIGHT);
            image.sendToFront();

        }
        if(ball.getY()<getHeight()-paddleRight.getHeight()){           // AI
            paddleRight.setLocation(getWidth()-2*WIDTH,ball.getY());
            image2.setLocation(getWidth()-2*WIDTH,ball.getY());
            image2.sendToFront();
        }
        else
            paddleRight.setLocation(getWidth()-2*WIDTH,getHeight()-paddleRight.getHeight());
            image2.setLocation(getWidth()-2*WIDTH,getHeight()-paddleRight.getHeight());
            image2.sendToFront();
```

Comment: Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: added a bit more code if that helps

Comment: The error pretty much says it all. What do you think the g variable is? You need to load your image ahead of time (at startup), and then use it in a paintComponent() method where you have access to a Graphics instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using a library from http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/ (based on the `GRect` class etc).

And it seems like you should be able to use a [GImage](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GImage.html) as well. So the code could roughly look like

```
Image myImage = getImage(getCodeBase(), "texture.png");
//g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0 , 10, 120, this);
GImage image = new GImage(myImage);
add(image);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library that you are using there. But first of all, insert a `System.out.println("myImage: "+myImage)` to make sure that the image path is correct and that the image is loaded properly (and that it is not `null`). Additionally, you might have to place the resulting `GImage` somehow, with `image.setLocation(200,200)` or something similar.

Comment: system.out resulted in `myImage: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage@48fd918a` is that correct? (not null) I did add setLocation earlier but it did nothing

Comment: Yes, every output that is not `null` should be OK. But again, it's hard to say what might be wrong there without actually *testing* this library. You could add the line `MediaTools.loadImage(myImage)` directly after your `getImage` call, but this is just a guess. It seems that there are no example applications in http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/demos/acm.graphics/index.html that involve *Images*, but maybe they are still worth a closer look...

Comment: I managed to load the image, I copied the texture into every sub-folder in my project and apparently one of them worked (i think it was bin, and previously i only had it in src, I'm using eclipse). look at the edit please

Comment: @user3450315 The part with `image.setLocation(WIDTH,getHeight()-HEIGHT);` looks strange. Shouldn't the `mouseY` appear there? However, it seems like this is unrelated to the original question. Maybe you create a new question for that. (But one has to assume that there is hardly anybody so familiar with this library that he can give an answer just by looking at a piece of code...)

Comment: Thank you for all your help, everything is finally working. The issue was in the last part of the code, (rookie mistake) i forgot to put { } after else, therefore second last and last lines we're being executed at all times, blocking the texture.